# How to remove certain buttons on Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

so I have this UI and when I click a button, it creates a new connection, so it calls this function:

```
def updateConnections(self, buttonName):

        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text = buttonName, size = (50, 50),
                                     background_color = (.3, .3, .3, 1),
                                     #on_release = self.background_color = (0, 40, 1, 1) ,
                                     size_hint = (1, None)))

        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text = 'X', size = (10, 10),
                                     size_hint = (.15, .1),
                                     background_normal = '',
                                     background_color = (1 , .5, .5, 1)))         

        print('updateConnections function ran successfully')
```

So basically, I want to know how can I remove the specified button if I click the X button, I can call a function on_release of that button, but I don't know how to access the specified button, to remove it. I've tried adding ID's to it, but for some reason it throws an error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `Button` to be removed to another method like this:

```
def updateConnections(self, buttonName):
    new_butt = Button(text=buttonName, size=(50, 50),
                                  background_color=(.3, .3, .3, 1),
                                  # on_release = self.background_color = (0, 40, 1, 1) ,
                                  size_hint=(1, None))
    self.layout.add_widget(new_butt)

    self.layout.add_widget(Button(text='X', size=(10, 10),
                                  size_hint=(.15, .1),
                                  background_normal='',
                                  on_release=partial(self.my_remove_widget,new_butt),
                                  background_color=(1, .5, .5, 1)))

    print('updateConnections function ran successfully')

# new method to remove the `Button` and its associated `X` `Button`
def my_remove_widget(self, but1, but2):
    self.layout.remove_widget(but1)
    self.layout.remove_widget(but2)
```